# Как фильтровать вставляемый текст из буффера обмена

Tags: javascript, jquery

Нужно сделать проверку на первый символ, перед тем как разрешить вставить текст в поле.

На данный момент получилось отловить действие вставки `onpaste` и остановить вставку(ctrl+v или "Вставить") `return false;`.

Как мне сейчас проверить какой текст пользователь пытается вставить?

```js
input.onpaste = function(event) {
  console.log(event.type + ' ' + input.value);
  return false;
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="input">
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В примере проверяем текст из буффера обмена.

Если первая буква вставляемого текста равна латинской букве `A`, то вставляем текст, если нет, то выводим ошибку.

```js
    input.onpaste = function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var data = event.clipboardData.getData('text'); // Получаем вставляемые данные
        var first = data[0]; //Получаем первую букву.

        if(first == "A"){ // Если вставляемый текст начинается на латинскую букву A, то вставляем текст
            document.getElementById('input').value = data;
        } else {
            document.getElementById('err').innerText = 'Нельзя вставлять такой текст.'
        }
    };
```

```html
<div id="err"></div>
<input type="text" id="input">
```